# When will Enceladus run out of water?

Tags: solar-system

So its geyser eruptions are the primary source of water in Saturn's atmosphere (from [this](http://www.reddit.com/r/science/comments/j3h4o/enceladus_is_the_primary_water_supply_for_saturns/) thread). And they even manage to contaminate Titan's atmosphere with it.

But has the outgassing rate decreased over time? Could it eventually run out of water?

Answer (score 5):

According to http://www.physorg.com/news/2011-06-strongest-evidence-icy-saturn-moon.html, Enceladus is losing 440 pounds of water vapor per second. Given Enceladus' mass of 1.08 x 10^20 kg, the maximum length of time this could go on is about 17 billion years! Hence, it can continue losing water vapor like this essentially indefinitely, at least as long as the orbital resonances with Dione, a larger satellite of Saturn, continue.

Comment: An important point to make here is that we also have no idea (a) how long this has been going on, (b) how long it will continue, and (c) if the rates have been steady.  So, any estimate at the moment is going to be based on a steady-state which is unlikely to be accurate.